# How can I make a timeout to load the page with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new with selenium. The script opens the links that are in an excel but I need to have a time limit for the page to load and if it doesn't load it goes to the next page.
I hope you can help me

Part of my code is:

```
excel_credenciales = r'C:\Users\EM\selenium\prueba.xlsx'  

df = pd.read_excel(excel_credenciales) 

mylist = df['url'].tolist() 

for url in mylist:
    browser.get(url)
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
    browser.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\E\SELENIUM\fotos'+timestamp+'.png')
browser.close()
```

Comment: Set pageloadtimeout.  Different drivers have different defaults already.  I think Firefox's is especially long (like 5mins?): https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Implicitly_wait function

```
driver.implicitly_wait(int)
```

like this

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

it will wait pages loading during setting time, if loading is done, it  goes to next code

Comment: Implicit wait is a polling loop that ignores element not found exceptions for a certain amount of time.  (globally for each webdriver method call that gets a webelement reference: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) After a .get() is used Selenium automatically waits for the page to load.